# How can I get vis.js charts to be rendered in Atom Editor correctly?

Tags: clojure, atom-editor, leiningen, vis.js, proto-repl

I'm playing around with the graph examples from proto-repl-charts in Atom.

However, the vis.js-based graphs seems not to work on my setup.

The following code

```
(prc/graph "A Graph from a map" {:nodes [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g] :edges [[:d :b] [:b :c] [:d :c] [:e :f] [:f :g] [:d :a] [:f :c]]})
```

leads to a graph with only blocks instead of any text displayed. Similar behavior with the loom graphs.

Any clue on what could cause this?

[image]

[image]